# Spark on kubernetes: driver dies -> executors hit self destruct sequence but do not die

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark

I have an issue wherein driver containers are being killed in such a way that the child processes (ie the spark driver) are not being cleaned up appropriately. This leaves leaked executors.  However, my understanding is that if executors should lose contact with the driver they should self destruct. Indeed they claim to do so, but then... do not.

> 21/02/25 17:43:59 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to /10.178.144.144:37811 after 2 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
>
> 21/02/25 17:43:59 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 8 remote fetches in 48 ms
>
> 21/02/25 17:43:59 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 21.223892 ms
>
> 21/02/25 17:43:59 INFO Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 97). 2661 bytes result sent to driver
>
> 21/02/26 19:56:58 ERROR CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Executor self-exiting due to : Driver 10.205.36.205:32000 disassociated! Shutting down.
>
> 21/02/26 19:56:58 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
>
> 21/02/26 19:56:58 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped

However, the executor docker container is still running and the executor process is still running inside. No further output.

**Edit: I've tracked this down to a deadlock in a shutdown hook**

```
"Thread-2" #26 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f6410231800 nid=0x2a2 waiting on condition [0x00007f63c3bf1000]
java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- parking to wait for <0x00000000c05a47b8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.awaitTermination(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1475)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedExecutorService.awaitTermination(Executors.java:675)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.MessageLoop.stop(MessageLoop.scala:60)org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher.$anonfun$stop$1(Dispatcher.scala:190)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher.$anonfun$stop$1$adapted(Dispatcher.scala:187)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher$$Lambda$214/337533935.apply(Unknown Source)
at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)
at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)
at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:56)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher.stop(Dispatcher.scala:187)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.cleanup(NettyRpcEnv.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.shutdown(NettyRpcEnv.scala:302)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.stop(SparkEnv.scala:96)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.stop(Executor.scala:292)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.$anonfun$new$2(Executor.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$Lambda$317/1046854795.apply$mcV$sp(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHook.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:214)
at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.$anonfun$runAll$2(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$Lambda$2192/1832515374.apply$mcV$sp(Unknown Source)
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1932)
at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.$anonfun$runAll$1(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$Lambda$2191/952019066.apply$mcV$sp(Unknown Source)
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.runAll(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anon$2.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:178)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$1.run(ShutdownHookManager.java:54)
```

Comment: What Spark version are you using? How do you run spark? Are you using custom images?

Comment: Spark 3.0.1 on Kubernetes in client mode. We use a custom image built on top of the one that ships with spark